# My SQL - getting values for specific search and then adding and finally putting in another column of same table

Tags: java, mysql, apache-poi

I want to add values of a certain search that I got after executing a certain query and finally put them in a different column of the same table separately.

select  TotalAmount from Payment_Data where CreatedAt like "%04-07%", insert into VendorPIAmount;

like I got values after executing the top query but I don't know how to add them and finally put them in another column.

Comment: You could clarify this question by providing sample data and expected outcome as text. please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Like stated above your question is very general. Do you need to do something with data contained in the first query? Or do you want to immediately insert them in another table/column? I don't see, why your question is tagged as 'Java' or 'Apache-POI'?

Comment: @RainerZufall I want to immediately insert them in another column after getting a query result. and it is tagged with java and apache poi because I am importing data from MySQL to excel with java.

Comment: @P.Salmon ok .....    select  column_name from table_name where column_name like "%value%" and whatever values I got I want to add them first and then want to put separately into another specified column. and one more thing I want to do everything with java code as I am importing data from MySQL to excel file. thank you!!

Comment: And guys sorry this is my first time posting a question that's why I am not good with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of some existing libraries and easy to implement this function, but if your data volume is relatively large, fastexcel is a very good replacement for apache poi.Reference:https://github.com/dhatim/fastexcel/ .In addition, hutool is a collection of great tools, which can easily operate the database. It also has many other commonly used functions, date format conversion, string processing, etc.
Reference:https://github.com/dromara/hutool

```java
package com.example.demo;

import cn.hutool.core.io.FileUtil;
import cn.hutool.db.DbUtil;
import cn.hutool.db.ds.simple.SimpleDataSource;
import org.dhatim.fastexcel.Color;
import org.dhatim.fastexcel.Workbook;
import org.dhatim.fastexcel.Worksheet;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;

public class DataExportTest {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    /**
     * export data to excel
     */
    @Test
    public void Test2() {
        LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.now();
        try (OutputStream os = FileUtil.getOutputStream("D:\\tmp\\TEST_DATA_2_EXCEL.xlsx")) {
            SimpleDataSource ds = new SimpleDataSource("jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/litemall", "root", "rooter", "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
            List<String> list = DbUtil.use(ds).query("SELECT TotalAmount  from Payment_Data where CreatedAt like ?", String.class, "%04-07%");
            Workbook wb = new Workbook(os, "MyApplication", "1.0");
            Worksheet ws = wb.newWorksheet("Sheet 1");
            ws.value(0, 0, "VendorPIAmount");
            ws.style(0, 0).fillColor(Color.GRAY2).set();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                ws.value(i + 1, 0, list.get(i));
            }
            wb.finish();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error", e);
        }
        LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.now();
        logger.info("Cost time {}", Duration.between(start, end).toMillis() + "ms");
    }
}
```

Dependencys:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.dhatim</groupId>
    <artifactId>fastexcel-reader</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>cn.hutool</groupId>
    <artifactId>hutool-all</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.16</version>
</dependency>
```

The table used in the code was created in the local mariadb database according to your description. The DDL is as follows.

```sql
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for payment_data
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `payment_data`;
CREATE TABLE `payment_data`  (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CreatedAt` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `TotalAmount` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of payment_data
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `payment_data` VALUES (1, 'DCBA01-17ABCD', 'AAA');
INSERT INTO `payment_data` VALUES (2, 'DEDCB02-32BCDE', 'BBB');
INSERT INTO `payment_data` VALUES (3, 'ASDF04-07FDSA', 'CCC');
INSERT INTO `payment_data` VALUES (4, 'ZXCV04-07VCXZ', 'DDD');
```